# Can't change jade variable

Tags: javascript, variables, pug, interpolation, template-engine

I'm gonna keep this short. I have this code:

```
- var title = 'title'

block content
  h1= title
  p Welcome to #{title}
```

Why does this not work? I have tried it without the variable and it works perfectly the, so the problem is about the variable.

Comment: Do you get an error?

Comment: no error, just no text in the tags... I get text as soon as I replace title with 'title'. It's really odd

Comment: I might have found the problem. It seems like `title` is in the scope of layout.jade. If I define title in layout.jade, it works. Is there any way around this to use the title in index.jade (the file this code is in) instead?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that since index.jade extended layout, when I defined the variable inside index.jade and then referenced it inside the block content, the references to it came before the definition.

The fix is simple: either define the variable in block content too:

```
block content
- var title = 'title'
  h1= title
  p Welcome to #{title}
```

Or if you want it to be able to the layout.jade too, just define it at the top of layout.jade.